# How can I stop/start all Mac OS X Server services at once?

Tags: osx-server

When doing maintenance on our OS X Server (10.8.4), I need to shut down all server services one by one. While it is not too much of a drag to click all services off, perform maintenance, and back on, I wonder, if there is a way to automate this procedure.

Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it from the command line and/or write a script with the relevant services:

```
sudo launchctl list
```

And for ssh (remote login) for example

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
```

Bringing them back up then with `start` (instead of stop)